# Storing values from an abstract int on start-up

Tags: java

so I have an abstract class and i'm willing to store all the values from the sub-classes in an ImmutableList. Here is an example on what I mean

```
public abstract class Test {

...

public abstract int getValue();

}
```

then the sub-class

```
public final class Example extends Test {

@Override
public int getValue() {
return 5;
}

}
```

Is there a way to store the Test#getValue() in an ImmutableList on start-up?

I tried doing something like

```
public abstract class Test {

    public static final ImmutableList<Integer> VALUES = ImmutableList.of();

    public Test() {
        VALUES.add(getValue());
    }

    public abstract int getValue();

}
```

then print out the values in the VALUES list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test.LIST.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

but it didnt work.

Comment: Do you want to store just one element? Try Collections.singletonList() or from google collection lib ImmutableList

Comment: @gauee yeah just an int. I've added an example of what I've tried to do.

Comment: You Cannot change state of immutable object after initialization phase. 
private  ImmutableList<Object> build = ImmutableList.builder().add("5").build(); Those values should be stored directly in implementation of abstract class. Another aproach is to create constructor with such values and return always a copy of such list.

Comment: It could be helpful in second approach: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html

Comment: @gauee Yeah I know that, you can do `private ImmutableList<Object> build = ImmutableList.of("5");` to avoid the extra characters. If I went with a List. How would that be done?

Comment: Calling alien methods (e.g. a method overridden in a subclass) in a constructor is considered bad practice. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327417/is-it-ok-to-call-abstract-method-from-constructor-in-java. Note that it is possible to avoid by simply passing the int value as a constructor parameter to `Test`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for your comment, I can use an enum and decouple the values from the abstract class and do something like `public static final ImmutableList<MyEnum> VALUES = Sets.immutableEnumSet(EnumSet.allOf(MyEnum.class));` but I wouldn't like decoupling because it only creates more unnecessary work.

Comment: What exactly do You want to achieve with storing some values in immutable list? Please explain exactlu for what immutable list do you need?

Comment: @gauee I want to compare values and check for a match, if I had a List with all the defined getValues() of the sub-classes I could do it. But I can't and thats why i asked help

Comment: Ok, I had got the point! I think that only way to do something like that is to use reflection mechanism in some seperate class. You need to create registry of all results of method getValue and store it later in list or even in map where key will be class name. This will be helpful https://code.google.com/p/reflections/

Answer (score 1):

use an [initializer block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).  It's possible to create a static block which will execute upon class load:

```
package foo.bar.baz;

import java.util.*;

public class Test {
  static {
    int MY_INT = 5;
    List<Object> mylist = new ArrayList<Object>();
    mylist.add(new Integer(MY_INT));
  }

  public Test() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: No, the abstract method isn't static so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in the main method like this :

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.TestClassExample");    
Set<Class<? extends >> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(TestExampleClass.class);
```

Get all the names of the classes and then loop through all the classes, and then cast it in the your test class and , then using and storing the values dynamically in a variable like this.

```
private static List<Integer> immutableList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Does this sound feasible for your problem ?

Comment: This isn't modular, having to do this for each sub-class is going to make my life harder.

Comment: @Jason Qlueses Is the edited answer helpful ? I can help you code it. Let me know.